# Mongo combine and or in a single query

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, mongoid3

I am trying to figure out the best way to query mongo.
I am using Mongoid and latest mongo version

What I want to do is query like this

user_id => [array of ids] and user_type => "some_type"
OR
user_id => [array of ids] and user_type => "some_type"

How can I do it in Mongo/Mongoid?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In mongo shell, it would be something like,

```
db.yourcollection.find({$or: [
    {user_id: {$in: [array_of_ids]}, user_type: "some_type"},
    {user_id: {$in: [array_of_ids2]}, user_type: "some_type2"}
]});
```